# Имя кнопки в Excel (VBA). Трудности рефакторинга

Tags: excel, vba, рефакторинг

Работаю с Excel ооочень редко.

На листах находятся некоторые элементы управления, например Кнопки (`CommanButton`).

Есть некоторый код. Для кнопок это в основном обработчики событий типа `CommandButton1_Click()`. Если я изменяю имя элемента через окошечко свойства, то код "отвязывается". Приходится выискивать соответствующий код и подгонять названия методов под новые названия элементов.

Как упростить рефакторинг? Возможно вообще это, что бы изменив имя элемента, методы изменялись соответствующим образом?

Comment: Даже работая в Excel редко, Вы умуряетесь усложнять себе жизнь :) Не применяйте ActiveX. Создайте любую фигуру и назначьте ей макрос.

Comment: Не так. Жизнь я хочу себе упростить. Мне достался сложный легаси документ, который нужно приветсти в порядок, а затем и добавить новый фунционал. Хотелось бы для начала дать значимые имена всем элементам управления, что бы понять, что куда растет.

Comment: вот и упрощайте. Совет из первого комментария. Время потратите, но в будущем избежите таких проблем

Comment: ответ прост - никак.